# Can you automatically retry a trigger if record validation fails without user intervention?

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule, before-trigger

We have a custom field with the `Unique Id` attribute. This field represents a randomly generated string that is used as a publicly facing identifier.

This `public id` field is randomly generated and populated in a `before insert` trigger. We don't care what the value is, just that it's unique.

However, there always exists a chance that the randomly generated identifier is not unique and thus record validation fails.

Is there anyway to for us to catch that exception somewhere and simply try again without informing the user of the validation error? All we really want to do is keep trying with a new `public id` until validation passes.

As it stands, there's a small chance this validation error can surface to the user and confuse them. Asking them to just "try again" solves the problem, but it's rather inelegant. Any techniques to avoid this?

*Note: We're not using UUIDs, but rather much smaller, more friendly identifiers, so the chance of a collision is slightly higher than "don't ever worry about it".*

Comment: This is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The solution is to use UUIDs or sequential (not random) values. The latter is available out of the box via the `Name` and you can slap a formula on it to transform it however you wish for public consumption. Or if you really want to bother with reinventing the wheel, you can do your own sequence with SELECT FOR...UPDATE along the lines of your previous question. All of these approaches have been discussed here - do a search.

Comment: UUIDs make for terrible public identifiers, while Salesforce's built-in `Auto-Number` fields leak potentially sensitive information. Generators like `Nano ID` offer a lot more flexibility when being universally unique is not a requirement. We're just trying to find a way to hide any potential exceptions from the user when the record is created but fails validation because of uniqueness. Since Salesforce is already doing the unique check given the field type, we'd rather leverage that.

Comment: The difference between this question and the other one, is that this one deals with a requirement that can be expressed using normal Salesforce validation rules (strict uniqueness) while the other one cannot.

Comment: There is no automatic approach, and none that would cover all possible scenarios (e.g. UI or REST record creations) without jumping some enormous hoops. I think you need to live with the minor leakage and use an auto-number. This only informs the user that a certain number of records have been created, and if you apply sharing appropriately they cannot use this to access data they should not.

Comment: Fair enough, we'll bump up the identifier length a tad and further reduce the likelihood of collisions. We're not worried about access issues. Rather, in some industries, knowing roughly how many records exist of something over a given time period is information that shouldn't be shared. Wikipedia refers to this as the _"German tank problem"_, but it's equally applicable to things like # of accounts, orders, invoices, etc...

Comment: @PhilW If you wish to migrate your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: _UUIDs make for terrible public identifiers_ - this depends on your goals. From a security perspective, they're [very good](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Comment: Well sure, they are great as object Ids that can be 'safely' exposed to the public, somewhat similar to SObject Ids. But they don't make for great identifiers that the public might interact with, like an Order Number, Agreement Number or Invoice Number. We need to create such numbers that are unique, non-sequential and reasonably easy to work with when humans are saying them to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic approach, and none that would cover all possible scenarios (e.g. UI or REST record creations) without jumping some enormous hoops (e.g. the identifier moved out to a separate custom object that gets populated via a single threaded async, and to use a cross-object formula to bring the identifier into the original record. There would be a period where the record would have no unique identifier, of course).

I think you need to live with the minor leakage and use an auto-number. This only informs the user that a certain number of records have been created prior to this record, and if you apply sharing appropriately they cannot use this to access data they should not.